# Can I run multiple hidden services without anyone knowing they are hosted on the same server?

Tags: onion-services, anonymity

I want to host multiple hidden services but I need it in a way that people cannot find out that they are all hosted on the same server. How could I do this?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that if you do run two hidden services on the same server, then an adversary can gain at least some information by noting when the two services are available and when they are not. If the server goes down, or, more particularly, if an adversary is able to crash the server, then even though it shouldn't be possible to determine where the services are hosted, the simultaneous disappearance of both hidden services will raise a strong suspicion that they are hosted together.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! However for best practice, you may want to have some kind of separation between the instances for better security. You have two options: 1. Run each hidden service instance in a separate virtual machine. 2. Run each hidden service in a separate container.

A third option, if you are Linux savvy but short on system resources is to set up vhosts. This will not provide any separation between the services and if one site gets hacked, then the whole system is at risk. At least in the case of VMs or containers, the hacker would then have to know how to break out of that and then get to your system (not a very easy task).

Comment: The hidden service will "subscribe" itself at some nodes. If one of these nodes receive multiple subscriptions from the same source it could know that they are hosted on the same server. Tor clients however do not have this information.